# XML @style in parent

Tags: android, android-theme

In the android examples style-parents are defined like this

```
 <style name="GreenText" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
```

but in the android sources i find

```
<style name="Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar.TabText" parent="Base.Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar.TabText">
```

whats the difference when i prefix with @style and @android:style or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, if you put "@android" in front of something, it means that you're looking for a resource defined in android package, not in your project.

For instance, if you're trying to get a color:

```
android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
```

This will get the Android holo_red_dark color. You don't have this color defined in your project.

```
android:background="@color/my_red_color"
```

This will get your "my_red_color" defined in your project.

Same goes for styles.

EDIT:
The thing is there is no difference between

```
parent="@style/MyStyle"
```

and

```
parent="MyStyle"
```

for a style compiled in your project. You might as well just write

```
<style name="Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar.TabText" parent="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar.TabText">
```

and it would work.

Thus, taking in account that `Base.Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar.TabText` is compiled in your project form the support library, you can add it with `@style` as prefix or without. However, `@android:style/TextAppearance` is from Android package, and that is why you have to specify `@android:` as a prefix.

I hope it is clear now

Comment: yes thats the difference between \@android:style and \@style, but i'm looking for the difference between parent="\@style/TextAppearance" and parent="TextAppearance"

Comment: ok means there is no difference either adding the \@style prefix to the parent attribute or not?

Comment: Yes - only when the referring style is defined in you project (by you, the developer, or in any library you have added - in this case, the support library).

Comment: means i cannot use \@style for parents which only exists in the platform?

Comment: Let me clear it up again: if it is in your project (by you or in a library), you can use BOTH "@style" or no prefix. If it is defined in Android package, you HAVE to use "@android:style" prefix

Answer (score 0):

Because developers in sources are inheriting style they defined themselves.

If you define

```
  <style name="CodeFont" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
        <item name="android:textColor">#00FF00</item>
    </style>
```

You don't need to write a parent from styles, but can just write

```
<style name="CodeFont.Red">
    <item name="android:textColor">#FF0000</item>
</style>
```

like so.

Explanation from here http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html#Inheritance

Notice that there is no parent attribute in the `<style>` tag, but because the name attribute begins with the CodeFont style name (which is a style that you have created), this style inherits all style properties from that style. This style then overrides the android:textColor property to make the text red. You can reference this new style as @style/CodeFont.Red.

You can continue inheriting like this as many times as you'd like, by chaining names with periods. For example, you can extend CodeFont.Red to be bigger, with:

```
<style name="CodeFont.Red.Big">
    <item name="android:textSize">30sp</item>
</style>
```

Comment: but if i use the parrent attribute, is there a difference when i prefix with "@style/" ?

Comment: If it's your style you can specify it without @style, otherwise you must put it before style name.

Comment: but i used often styles which are not mine without the prefix: <style name="MyAPp.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle" parent="TextAppearance.Sherlock.Widget.ActionBar.Title">

Comment: You have sources of both? If, then it counts as your code. This is just a prefix to get compiler to look in the right direction.